# What has changed in the new edition of Junta?

Tags: junta

I have the 1985 WEG version of [Junta](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/242/junta) (that I rescued from a second-hand store years ago), and while it's a favorite of mine, I'll easily admit that it's not the clearest game for explanations or text on cards.

I see that [Alderac is printing a new edition](http://www.alderac.com/junta) - is it just a cleanup, or are there mechanical differences?

Comment: Not to be confused with the 2010 [Junta: Viva el Presidente](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/84159/junta-viva-el-presidente) by Z-Man Games.

Comment: The 1985 version you're talking about is the 2nd edition of Junta. The 3rd edition is from 2005, here's a list of changes: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/198305/exhaustive-list-changes-third-edition

Comment: Short version: 1) First fire has been eliminated, shooting is simultaneous for everyone. 2) minor changes to retreats. 3) unit transfer during Coup Phase. 4) optional rules for longer/shorter games.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this review](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/18/18486.phtml), which relied on the reviewer's memory for some details of the original, there are some functional differences:

- *Marxists Leninists* card removed.
- First Fire rule removed.

Also variants have been added to allow players to make the game longer or shorter, variants not given in the original.

> These include timed rounds, modifications on who can start a coup, the foreign aid stack getting exhausted more expediently, or conversely all used bills going back into the stack. Additional house rules include players in Exile participating in coups via bribes, assassinations being blocked via assassin cards etc.

And according to this [BGG post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1606216/article/23208773#23208773), there's also

- change to the rules for going into exile